# How to store incoming json via websocket to SQL database

Tags: python, sql, pandas, postgresql, psycopg2

to start I am very new to python (and coding period) so I apologize if I am going about this the wrong way.

I am receiving these json messages from a websocket stream:

```
import websocket, json, dateutil.parser
import dateparser
import csv
import itertools


current_tick = None
dataframe = []
symbols = 'AAPL', 'FB', 'AMZN', 'NFLX'

def on_open(ws):
    print("opened")
    auth_data = {
        "action": "auth",
        "params": 'APIKEY'
    }

    ws.send(json.dumps(auth_data))

    for s in symbols:
        channel_data = {
            "action": "subscribe",
            "params": s
        }

        ws.send(json.dumps(channel_data))


def on_message(ws, message):
    global current_tick, dataframe

    current_tick = json.loads(message)
  
    print(current_tick)


    if current_tick[0]['ev'] == 'T':            
        dataframe.append(current_tick)

        
def on_close(ws):
    print("closed connection")

    socket = "WEBSITE"

    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(socket, on_open=on_open, on_message=on_message, on_close=on_close)
    #ws.run_forever()
```

**OUTPUTS:**

```
[{'ev': 'T', 'sym': 'AAPL', 'i': '227161', 'x': 4, 'p': 134.605, 's': 100, 't': 1609275343055, 'z': 3}]
[{'ev': 'T', 'sym': 'AAPL', 'i': '227162', 'x': 4, 'p': 134.605, 's': 3, 'c': [37], 't': 1609275343072, 'z': 3}]
[{'ev': 'T', 'sym': 'AAPL', 'i': '155273', 'x': 12, 'p': 134.6, 's': 25, 'c': [14, 37, 41], 't': 1609275343104, 'z': 3}]
[{'ev': 'T', 'sym': 'FB', 'i': '47501', 'x': 4, 'p': 276.5, 's': 1, 'c': [12, 37], 't': 1609276352067, 'z': 3}]
[{'ev': 'T', 'sym': 'NFLX', 'i': '10420', 'x': 11, 'p': 531.5, 's': 147, 'c': [14, 12, 41], 't': 1609276352376, 'z': 3}]
```

My goal is to to store these into SQL database as they come in, this is what I have so far

```
import psycopg2
postgresConnection = psycopg2.connect(
    host='HOST',
    user='USER',
    password='PASSWORD',
    database='DATABASE'
cursor= postgresConnection.cursor()
sqlCreateTable = "create table datas(sym varchar(256), price int, size int, exchange int, time int);"
cursor.execute(sqlCreateTable)
postgresConnection.commit()

sqlpoptable = "intert into datas(sym, price, size) VALUES(%(sym)s, %(price)s, %(size)s)", {"sym":current_tick['sym'],"price":current_tick['p'], "size":current_tick['s']}
cursor.execute(sqlpoptable)
postgresConnection.commit()
```

And my output is:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may already know, you can access array data using an index. An index is a number that represents the data's position in the array, starting with the number zero.

If you have an array of items like this:

```py
items = ['a', 'z', 'c', 'd']
```

Then the index of `'a'` would be 0, the index of `'z'` would be 1, the index of `'c`' would be 2, and so on.

If you wrote some Python code that looked like this:

```py
items = ['a', 'z', 'c', 'd']
myChosenItem = items[0]
```

Then `myChosenItem` would be equal to `'a'`. Make sense?

The error you are getting is telling you that you tried to provide something other than an integer (a whole number) as an index when getting data out of an array.

That would be like writing this:

```py
items = ['a', 'z', 'c', 'd']
myChosenItem = items['chicken']
```

Python would have no idea what you meant. Look at your code and figure out where you are accessing array data using an index, and then figure out if that index is an integer or not. Then you should be able to get this error to go away.